# problema com array multidimensional não pega valor

Tags: php

```
 $dados= '{"nome":"teste","cpf":"teste"}';
 $value = json_decode($dados, TRUE);

foreach($value as $in)
{
$nome = $in->{'nome'};
$cpf = $in->{'cpf'};
}
```

eu to tentando pegar os dados, mas o valor nome e cpf vem null!!!

Comment: Esse não é um array multidimencional

Answer (score 2):

Tente da seguinte forma:

```
$dados= '[{"nome":"teste","cpf":"teste"}]';
$value= json_decode($dados, TRUE);
foreach($vaue as $in)
{
  $nome = $in['nome'];
  $cpf $in['cpf']; 
}
```

Comment: era isso mesmo, obrigado!

Comment: @fernando Seguindo, marque como resposta certa para ajudar outros que tenham a mesma dúvida.